# Pygame sometimes not detecting key presses

Tags: python, pygame

So, my problem is that this code I front for pygame (show below) detects key presses and sometimes doesn't. The code's function is to display a random string of letters and the game is won or lost based on if the letters are pressed in the right order. The problem arises when the code randomly doesn't pick up on some of the key presses, and especially doesn't work when a key is held down. When a key is held down, the game dispalys that a key is being presses, but is unable to say what that key is. I'm sure there is a simple solution this this, but I cannot figure it out.

```
letters = ['w', 'a', 's', 'd', 'e']
random.shuffle(letters)
print(letters)

number = 0
smthnghppnd = 'n'
while number < 5:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and number < 5 and smthnghppnd == 'n':
   print('down')
   print(event.unicode)
   if event.unicode == '':
    pass
   elif event.unicode == letters[number]: 
    print(letters[number])
    number += 1
    smthnghppnd = 'y'
   else:
    print('no ' + letters[number])
    number = 7
  if len(pygame.event.get()) == 0 and smthnghppnd == 'y':
   smthnghppnd = 'n'
   print('up')

if number == 7:
 print('lose')
else:
 print('win')
```

Comment: The code look like it would work. Please provide a small runnable script that we can test with. Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is that you call `pygame.event.get()` multiple times per frame. Just call it only once and you won't miss events.

Comment: `while number < 5` suggests that this isn't your main loop. As sloth said you are probably calling `pygame.event.get()` multiple times. Only call it once in the main loop and do all the event handling there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the subprocess in pygame is not working correctly. The code does look right, so I suggest you post a runnable script as @Mike67 said. If not instead of using pygame.KEYDOWN try using keyboard or pyautogui module.

They are available here.

https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/

Comment: You may also use win32api module

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sloth, it was as simple as changing the

```
if len(pygame.event.get()) == 0 and smthnghppnd == 'y':
```

to

```
if smthnghppnd == 'y' and len(pygame.event.get()) == 0:
```

Since it isn't running pygame.event.get() multiple times per frame, it works perfectly.